# Equivalency between $\max \{ 0, 1 - \exp[g(x)]\}$ and $\max \{0, -g(x)\}$ (with err term)

Tags: calculus

$$\begin{align} &\max \{0, 1-\exp [\log f(x+h) - \log f(x)]\} \\ &= \max \{0, 1-\exp[\nabla \log f(x)h +o(h)] \} 
\\ &= \max\{0, -\nabla f(x) h\}+o(h) \end{align}$$

where $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f(x) > 0$, $f(x)$ is twice differentiable, and $h$ small.

I see the first step is by definition of differentials, but I have trouble seeing how the second equation is true...

Comment: The second step uses the series expansion of $\displaystyle e^x = \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}$.

Comment: OH...........!!!! I will give it a try, thank you @sudeep5221 !!!